# What is the difference between TimeToLive and expiry-address in ActiveMQ JMS?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Can you explain me the difference between timeToLive and expiry-address properties in ActiveMQ Artemis?

It's not so much clear what are the differences and if they are independent or complementary.

http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-expiry.html

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These features are complementary. The JMS API allows one to set a `TimeToLive` on messages. When the broker receives a message with a `TimeToLive` it will monitor that message and when the set time elapses then the message will be "expired" as configured. Expired messages can be sent to an expiry address or they can simply be deleted. The broker can also enforce its own `TimeToLive` on incoming messages via the `<expiry-delay>` `<address-setting>`.